# TypeError when using a tuple as input to a class method

Tags: python, vtk

The problem happens specifically with a VTK object called vtkTransform. The method is RotateWXYZ(angle, x, y, z). This works fine:

```
transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
transform.RotateWXYZ(45,0,1,0)
```

But when trying to input a tuple:

```
a = (45,0,1,0)
transform.RotateWXYZ(a)
```

I receive the following message:

> TypeError: no overloads of RotateWXYZ() take 1 argument

How can I "unpack" the tuple for the method to receive the values as individual inputs?

Comment: `transform.RotateWXYZ(*a)`, see the duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**

As Martijn revealed above the best solution is

```
transform.RotateWXYZ(*a)
```

as to transform.RotateWXYZ() have to pass **4 arguments**, not **one tuple**.

```
transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
transform.RotateWXYZ(45,0,1,0)
```

Or alternatively you **can** do:

```
a = (45,0,1,0)
transform.RotateWXYZ(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3])
```

Comment: No,  you don't have to do that at all. See the duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but you can for sure, you always have more solution. It seems, it is not the best, but definitely one of them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No reason for downvote at all, this manner is destructive.

Comment: Please don't make assumptions who votes or why. That I commented does not mean I also voted. Voting is not 'destructive', it merely ranks answers by their perceived usefulness.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, sry for quick assumption, but anyway, if the downvoting doesn't server the diversity in any way and the answer isn't WRONG, then that is destructive.

Comment: Voting is about *usefulness* and helpfulness, not technically being right or wrong. Your answer is wrong, however, as you are stating that you 'have to' use individual indexes. You don't 'have to'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is actually helpful in several situation and the others, like "have to" vs. "can" are just semantics.

Comment: and that's where we disagree, and voting is subjective and personal. Don't tell people how to vote, and take feedback as it is: information for you to help improve the post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes doesn't agree as "information for you to help improve the post" is mostly more useful to comment it.

Comment: Thanks but the duplicate answered my question. Thank you and sorry for the repost.

Comment: My pleasure @bdemin and I modified my answer.